# Missing combinations when collapsing a data.frame [because 0 occurrences]

Tags: r, aggregate, zero

Let suppose we have a big `data.frame` named `df` with three different variables:

- `Gender`: which can be M or F (2 possible answers)
- `Hair`: which can be "black", "brown", "blond", "red", "other" (5 possible values)
- `Sport`: which can be "yes" or "no" (2 different values)
- `Value`: always 1 in order to count the number of events

When I use the `collap` function from `collapse` package I run the following code

```
collap (df, ~ Gender + Hair + Sport, FUN = sum, cols ="Value")
```

What I expect is a `data.frame` with 20 different rows (one per each combination); however, if there is a combination with no occurrences, the row does not appear.

Do you know how can I get all the possible combinations with a 0 in case there are no events with the required values?

Answer (score 0):

You can complete unused factor levels like this, resulting in a row for the females despite all rows in the data are males:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(collapse)
#> collapse 1.7.6, see ?`collapse-package` or ?`collapse-documentation`
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'collapse'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     D

data <- tribble(
  ~Gender, ~Hair, ~Value,
  "M", "black", 1
)

data %>%
  mutate(Gender = Gender %>% factor(levels = c("M", "F"))) %>%
  complete(Gender, fill = list(Value = 0)) %>%
  collap(~ Gender + Hair, FUN = sum, cols = "Value")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Gender Hair  Value
#>   <fct>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 M      black     1
#> 2 F      <NA>      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is not what I was looking for. It does not work for me. The fact is that all the variables have all the possible values, nevertheless, there is not a combination for `Gender = M   &   Hair = "red"  & Sport = "No"`, but I want a row where it's value is 0

Comment: Use `complete(Gender,Hair,Sport)` to get the whole cross product of all possible combinations across these three variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question based on the response by @danloo

```
df %<%
   complete(Gender, Hair, Sport) %>%
   collap( ~Gender + Hair + Sport, FUN = sum, cols = "Value")
```

Running that I get a `data.frame` with 20 different rows where `NA` are placed for those combinations with no events.